# Access Denied error while trying to use INamedBucketProvider to connect on Couchbase from C# application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, couchbase

I'm trying to use the interface `INamedBucketProvider`, but I'm getting the "Access Denied" error.
When I try to connect using just the `IBucketProvider`, it works perfectly.

Here are some important parts of my code:

```cs
public interface ICustomerBucketProvider : INamedBucketProvider
{
    // nothing goes in here!
}
```

```cs
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCouchbaseConnector(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCouchbase(opt => 
        {
            opt.ConnectionString = "couchbase://localhost";
            opt.UserName = "Administrator";
            opt.Password = "asd123";
            opt.Buckets = new[] { "customers" };
        });

        services.AddCouchbaseBucket<ICustomerBucketProvider>("customers");

        return services;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class NativeInjectorBootStrapper
{
    public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...

        services.AddCouchbaseConnector();
    }
}
```

This works:

```cs
private readonly IBucketProvider _bucketProvider;

public CustomerEventHandler(IBucketProvider bucketProvider)
{
    _bucketProvider = bucketProvider;
}

private async Task<ICouchbaseCollection> GetCouchbaseCollection()
{
    var bucket = await _bucketProvider.GetBucketAsync("customers");
    var collection = bucket.DefaultCollection();
    return collection;
}
```

And this doesn't work:

```cs
private readonly ICustomerBucketProvider _customerBucketProvider;

public CustomerEventHandler(ICustomerBucketProvider customerBucketProvider)
{
    _customerBucketProvider = customerBucketProvider;
}

private async Task<ICouchbaseCollection> GetCouchbaseCollection()
{
    var bucket = await _customerBucketProvider.GetBucketAsync();
    var collection = bucket.DefaultCollection();
    return collection;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For the record, this was also asked on Github, and there is some further discussion there: https://github.com/brantburnett/Couchbase.Extensions/issues/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I decided to implement my own structure to handle buckets and collections:

```cs
public interface ICouchbaseBucketBase
{
    public ICouchbaseCollection DefaultCollection { get; }
}

public class CouchbaseBucketBase : ICouchbaseBucketBase
{
    public ICouchbaseCollection DefaultCollection { get; private set; }

    protected readonly IBucket _bucket;

    public CouchbaseBucketBase(IBucketProvider bucketProvider, string bucketName)
    {
        _bucket = bucketProvider.GetBucketAsync(bucketName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        DefaultCollection = GetCollection();
    }

    protected ICouchbaseCollection GetCollection(string collectionName = null) =>
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(collectionName) ?
        _bucket.Collection(collectionName) : _bucket.DefaultCollection();
}
```

```cs
public interface ICustomerBucket : ICouchbaseBucketBase { }

public class CustomerBucket : CouchbaseBucketBase, ICustomerBucket
{
    //public ICouchbaseCollection OtherNonDefaultCollection { get; private set; }

    public CustomerBucket(IBucketProvider bucketProvider) : base(bucketProvider, "customers")
    {
        //OtherNonDefaultCollection = GetCollection("OtherNonDefault");
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCouchbaseConnector(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCouchbase(opt =>
        {
            opt.ConnectionString = "couchbase://localhost";
            opt.UserName = "Administrator";
            opt.Password = "asd123";
            opt.Buckets = new[] { "customers" };
        });

        services.AddTransient<ICustomerBucket, CustomerBucket>();

        return services;
    }
}
```